# Android getting images from DCIM folder

Tags: android

I'm building gallery application. I get the path of pictures in the code as in the image. In the logcat I can see the message of `I/DCIM PATH: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera` and I have 3 pictures in this folder. However the code doesn't list files inside it and gives an error of `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference.` What is wrong here? Also is there library to retrieve image from storage?

```
    private void getImagesFromDCIM() {
    pDialog.setMessage("Fetching images from DCIM folder...");
    pDialog.show();

    File dcimPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/Camera");
    if (dcimPath.exists()) {
        Log.i("DCIM PATH", dcimPath.toString());
        pDialog.hide();
        Log.i("DCIM PATH", dcimPath.listFiles().toString());
        File[] files = dcimPath.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Image image = new Image(files[i].getName(), files[i].toString());
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        pDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you add the permission in manifest?

Comment: yes I added, no problem with permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, the code works correctly. I just give permission my application by `Settings > Apps > "MyApplication" > Permissions > Storage` and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found out what the problem is.

Call `listFiles()` only once!